# Batch code to temporarily disable mouse input

Tags: windows, batch-file, cursor, mouse, legacy

I need to have a batch file that starts after program.exe starts that will **TEMPORARILY** disable mouse input.

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
    rem ---------------------------------
    rem Disable Mouse
    set key="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\system\CurrentControlSet\Services\Mouclass"
    reg delete %key%
    reg add %key% /v Start /t REG_DWORD /d 4
    rem ---------------------------------
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Also need to have XP and win7 variants, if they are required.

Comment: Can I ask why you would need this functionality? I'll say this... it is not a very good UX to have my mouse disabled. Unless this is for a prank, I'd imagine there is a better solution.

Comment: To prevent any disturbance to a playing video.

Comment: Modifying the registry won't do anything by itself - you'd also need to stop (and later restart) the service. However (at least on Win7) Windows does not allow stopping the `Mouclass` service (giving the error "The requested control is not valid for this service").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO "Please pull the mouse cord out of the PC..."
<do stuff>
ECHO "Please plug the mouse cord back into PC."
EXIT /B 0
```

Sorry, couldn't resist.

In seriousness though, you probably shouldn't rely on storing a registry key in a value of a batch file. What happens if the file is terminated prematurely? Power failure? An error in the script?

If the above in your example actually works (I haven't tried it), at least use the `reg export` to export to a temporary file, and then `reg import` to put it back. You can delete the temp file after successful `reg import` (make sure you check the `%ERRORLEVEL%` of `reg import`, not just write the command on next line, or at least link it with `&&` such as `reg import %file% && del /q %file%`

More on the **[reg command](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html)**